# My update.js.erb file only runs on the first button click and not on subsequent clicks (change a button's class and value on click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a todo list app with a complete/incomplete button for tasks.  I want to toggle between making the button class and button value change when I click it.  I get the button to change the first click, but subsequent clicks to the same button do not alter the button.  I checked my logs and the todo#update method is called after the first click but it doesn't seem to be running my javascript code in update.js.erb after the first click.

In my update.js.erb file:

```
// change color
$("#todo-button-<%=@todo_id%>").attr('class', "<%=button_class%>");

// change button text
$("#todo-button-<%=@todo_id%>").attr('value', "<%=button_status%>");
```

This is the button in index.html.erb

```
<%= button_to button_status,
    update_todo_path( todo_id: todo["id"],
                      description: todo["description"],
                      is_complete: todo["is_complete"]
                      ),
    remote: true,
    class: "#{button_class}",
    id: "todo-button-#{todo["id"]}"%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using a click function instead.  My code is more verbose than what I wanted but works:

```
$('.todo-button').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("btn-primary")){
        $(this).removeClass("btn-primary");
        $(this).addClass("btn-success");
        $(this).val("Incomplete");
    }else  if($(this).hasClass("btn-success")){
        $(this).removeClass("btn-success");
        $(this).addClass("btn-primary");
        $(this).val("Complete");
    }
});
```